# Filter data to facebook graph with json-python

Tags: python, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I 'm getting Facebook graph and data already shows what I need , but I could not filter the 'message' and 'id' or JSON , appreciate them , I leave my code:

```
import facebook
import json
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen

page_id = "MYPAGE" 
access_token = 'MY-ACCESS-TOKEN'
api_endpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/"
fb_graph_url = page_id+"?fields=id,name,feed.since(2015-12-22).until(2015-12-25){comments.filter(stream)}&access_token="+access_token
html = api_endpoint + fb_graph_url
print(html,"\n")
data = urllib.request.urlopen(html)
read_page= data.read()
print(read_page)
print(data.read(),"\n")
data2=json.loads(read_page.decode())
#message=data2["feed"]["data"]
message=data2
for item in message['feed']['data'][1]['comments']['data']:
   print(item['message'])
   print(item['from']['name'])
```

print(message,"\n")
He shows me something like:

```
{
   "id": "2825921296",
   "name": "MY-PAGE",
   "feed": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "2825921296_5155340"
         },
         {
            "id": "2825921296_5155340",
            "comments": {
               "data": [
                  {
                     "from": {
                        "name": "Carl Jhon",
                        "id": "282564921296"
                     },
                     "message": "Comment one",
                     "created_time": "2015-12-10T03:42:05+0000",
                     "id": "5153352885_5153353484206"
                  },
                  {
```

And my question is , How to display only the 'message' and 'name' of all it shows.
Thankl and I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable "message" in your code (not in the JSON data) is a dictionary. Subsequently, you can access the name and the first message by adding:

```
print(message['feed']['data'][1]['comments']['data'][0]['message'])
print(message['name'])
```

You can access the nth message with:

```
print(message['feed']['data'][1]['comments']['data'][n]['message'])
```

To print all of the messages, including the name of the author, you could use the for loop like this:

```
for item in message['feed']['data'][1]['comments']['data']:
    print(item['message'])
    print(item['from']['name'])
```

Or you can output a specific number of messages and names (100 in this case):

```
if len(message['feed']['data'][1]['comments']['data'])>=100:
    for i in range(100):
        print(message['feed']['data'][1]['comments']['data'][i]['message'])
        print(message['feed']['data'][1]['comments']['data'][i]['from']['name'])
```

In case the message contains emojis, you can either add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of your script or take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707222/print-python-emoji-as-unicode-string)

Comment: Hi, Markus K, i get error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Is the posted output stored in "message"? If not, you have to replace "message" in my code with the real variable name

Comment: Oh!!! Great! It worked , but show me a single message , how I can show other messages ?

Comment: Yeah, what I mean is if they are 100 comments with a FOR loop ?

Comment: Good, its work!, but i have a question, How best answer I can give you ? I deeply appreciate the help Markus :) You 're very kind

I do not know if it would be too much trouble for you to tell me why you access the dictionary that way

Comment: Ah, and the name of who made ​​the comment ( 'name')? in for loop?

Comment: ¡Oh! I understand , however , the name of the "message" of the page, it is not necessary , but if the 'message' of the author ...
For example :
Ana
Oh , great !!!
Jhon
Good :)
my Page
Yeah!

Comment: i get error:
    for item in message['feed']['data'][1]['comments']['data']:
KeyError: 'comments'

Comment: Please change the line `message=data2["feed"]["data"]` in your code to `message=data2`. It should work then

Comment: But I did not work, I've edited the post with my current code ... Is there a mistake ? still shows the error:
    message for item in [' feed' ] [' data' ] [1 ] [ 'comments' ] [' data' ] :
KeyError ' comments'

Comment: Please check, whether your session has expired. If this was the case, you would have to obtain a new access token

Comment: Oh! my error, good!!! thanks!!! but i get error to get comments:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 1475-1475: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

¿Parse? ¿Unicode?

Comment: Oh, work!! Thanks Markus and happy year! :) Contact email for you or facebook? :) Thanks...