# Python json.dumps() doesn't encode emojis properly

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

Why does json.dumps() encode emojis into unicode? See code and output below:

```
import json
obj = {"key": "hello "}
print(obj)
```

> {'key': 'hello '}

```
print(json.dumps(obj))
```

> '{"key": "hello \ud83d\ude00"}'

I have tried `print(json.dumps(obj)).encode('utf-8')` and some variants (`.decode()`...) but it didn't change the output much. Im working on Python 3.6.1

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707222/print-python-emoji-as-unicode-string

Comment: @ChetanAmeta Thanks but this shows how to go from smiley to \ud83... not the other way around

Comment: @Thomas do you want to load from \ud83 to smiley ? is this your requirement ?

Comment: @Murali yes indeed

Comment: @Thomas In that case dump it normally to a file, but when you load it mention the  encoding as "utf-8". doesn't it solve your problem?

Comment: @Murali see accepted answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
print(json.dumps(obj, ensure_ascii=False))
```

However, the ASCII variant is more portable, since you are almost guaranteed you won't have encoding problems. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#character-encodings)