# How to dynamically specify unicode string in Python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, emoji

Per [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52953582/3370173), Python allows using the name of unicode characters to get the characters.

For example:

```
print('\N{large red circle}')
```

I am trying to figure out how to use the above functionality without knowing the name in advance. i.e. something like:

```
name = "large red circle"
emoji = some_code(name) # some code to use the above to produce '\N{large red circle}' without third party packages like 'emoji'
print(emoji)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found one way [here](http://xahlee.info/python/unicodedata_module.html):

```
import unicodedata
name = "large red circle"
emoji = unicodedata.lookup(name)
print(emoji)
```