# Selenium: click the emoji button on Instagram and select an emoji from it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I was unable to send emojis with send_key, so I decided to just click the emoji button on Instagram and select an emoji from it

I tried to use this code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/main/div[1]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/button/div[1]/svg").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button/div").click()
```

but I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/main/div[1]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/button/div[1]/svg"}
```

Comment: Where is that emojis ? Can share us the `HTML` source for that element ?

Comment: Might be a synchronization issue which means you have to use an implicit wait or an explicit wait in order to click the element. on another note, avoid using absolute path because I can guarantee the path to the emoji changes which leads to `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Just write the emoji from a str. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68562976/20443541

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

From the code I could understand that in the first line, you are selecting the precise XPATH of the emoji's svg instead of selecting the button itself. You can try the below suggestion.

1. Try selecting upto the button tag, rather than selecting the svg of the emoji.

Instead of

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/main/div[1]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/button/div[1]/svg").click()
```

Try this

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/button").click()
```

**NOTE:** I'm copying the `full XPATH` of the elements.

I hope this would help you.